# Open any clicked hyperlinks in another browser or 1st Window Instance

Tags: google-chrome

Due to specific work requirement, I have a need to monitor URLs in one browser window, but open them in another, either another (already opened and existing) browser window or completely different browser app - like Firefox, does not matter.
Obviously I could right click -> copy but I have to process like 30+ URLs per ~10 minutes, I will kill my hand, whcih is already carpal ridden.

I found a few similar questions from a few years ago on SO but they dont have the solutions, there is some extensions like `CopyTabs` but it does this for opened tabs.

**EDIT:**
Example: I have 2 Chrome windows open, one (W1) contains only one tab in which I receive a stream of hyperlinks, another one (W2) is empty but it **pre-exists**. When I click any link in W1 I want it to be open in a new tab in W2.
**Or, alternatively**, I have Chrome window open, in which I click hyperlink and it forcefully open it in another browser (which is set to be a single instance only, so it will automatically open new tab in there).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's stopping you from just right click open in new tab, or even, as I have here, an extra button on my mouse assigned to just that task.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you may use the following to open any given link in
a new window:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the link will open it
in a new window.

If you wish to open the link in another window, you may
drag-and-drop the link into that window.

Otherwise, this will require an extension.

[**Open in specific window**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-specific-window/nkgphogbgnehgdfkpiknbdnjaamlbgmo)

> If you have multiple chrome windows open, this extension will add a right-click menu allowing you to choose which window to open the link in.

Comment: I have clarified the question, sorry

Comment: I added more options.